# How can you modify two matching delimiters at once with Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, tex

While this question concerns the formatting of LaTeX within Emacs (and maybe Auctex), I believe this can be applied to more general situations in Emacs concerning delimiters like parentheses, brackets, and braces.

I am looking to be able to do the following with Emacs (and elisp), and don't know where to begin. Say I have:

```
(This is in parentheses)
```

With some keybinding in Emacs, I want Emacs to find the matching delimiter to whichever one is by my cursor (something I know Emacs can do since it can highlight matching delimiters in various modes) and be able to change both of them to

```
\left( This is in parentheses \right)
```

The delimiters I would like this to work with are: `(...)`, `[...]`, `\lvert ... \rvert`, `\langle ... \rangle`, `\{ ... \}`. What elisp would I need to accomplish this task?

More general ways to handle matching delimiters are welcome.

Comment: +1 Nice idea! Such a thing would always be useful...

Comment: Please clarify where the modification came from?  Is the modification always a matter of prepending "\left" and "\right" to the delimiters?

Comment: The modification comes from LaTeX since the `\left` and `\right` make those delimiters scale to the size of the text/math contained within them (sometimes I'm not prescient enough to realize I'll need them). And yes, the modification would be a matter of prepending `\left` and `\right` to delimiters. However, if there are ways to do other things to them (change parentheses to brackets or braces, for example), that would be nice as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Evaluate the command below in Emacs.  After reloading you can put the point (text cursor) immediately after a closing paren.  Then do `M-x replace-matching-parens` to replace the closing `)` with `\right)` and the matching start paren `(` with `\left(`.

```
(defun replace-matching-parens ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let ((end-point (point)))
      (backward-list)
      (let ((start-point (point)))
        (goto-char end-point)
        (re-search-backward ")" nil t)
        (replace-match " \\\\right)" nil nil)

        (goto-char start-point)
        (re-search-forward "(" nil t)
        (replace-match "\\\\left( " nil nil)))))
```

The `interactive` bit indicates that I want a "command", so it can be executed using `M-x`.  To avoid the cursor ending up in a strange place after execution I'm wrapping the logic in `save-excursion`.  The point jumps back to the opening paren using `backward-list` and holds on to the start and end positions of the paren-matched region.  Lastly, starting at the end and working backwards I replace the strings.  By replacing backwards rather than forwards I avoid invalidating `end-point` before I need it.

Generalizing this to handle different kinds of delimiters shouldn't be too bad.  `backward-list` ought to work with any pair of strings emacs recognizes as analogues of `(` and `)`.  To add more parenthesis-like string pairs, check out `set-syntax-table` in this [Parenthesis Matching](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParenthesisMatching) article.

Use [`global-set-key`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html#Init-Rebinding) to setup a key binding to `replace-matching-parens`.

*Fair warning*: `replace-matching-parens` is the first elisp command I've implemented, so it may not align with best practices.  To all the gurus out there, I'm open to constructive criticism.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Works like a charm.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Thanks for giving me a good elisp challenge.